# Python replace different character

Tags: python, string, replace, substring

I have different strings like these :

```
"/table[1]/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tr/td[2]/p/b/text()"
"/table[1]/tr/td[2]/table[3]/tr/td[2]/p/b/text()"
```

I'd like to change the substring `"/table[" + some number + "]"` with `"/table[" + the same number + "]/tbody"`.

For example this string

```
"/table[1]/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tr/td[2]/p/b/text()"
```

should change in

```
"/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/p/b/text()"
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: pretty soon SO will be the place where we can see questions like this - "I need this and that and you MUST provide me with the best solution"

Comment: sorry it's my first question, I had already tried a few things, haven't wrote them here since they were not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [symbolic group naming](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax), this way:

```
>>> s
'/table[1]/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tr/td[2]/p/b/text()'
>>>
>>> re.sub(r'(?P<table>/table\[\d+\])', r'\g<table>/tbody', s)
'/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/p/b/text()'
>>>
>>> #similarly you can also reference by group number
>>> re.sub(r'(?P<table>/table\[\d+\])', r'\g<1>/tbody', s) 
'/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[2]/p/b/text()'
```

Quoting from [Python Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> `(?P<name>...)` 
>   Similar to regular parentheses, but the substring
>   matched by the group is accessible via the symbolic group name name.
>   Group names must be valid Python identifiers, and each group name must
>   be defined only once within a regular expression. A symbolic group is
>   also a numbered group, just as if the group were not named.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution :

```
import re

s = "/table[1]/tr/td[2]/table[2]/tr/td[2]/p/b/text()"
sl = s.split("/")

new_str = []
for n in sl :
    match = re.search(r'table\[(?P<num>\d+)\]$', n)
    if match != None :
        #if you want to get the num
        #num = match.group('num')
        new_str.append("{}/tbody".format(n))  
    else :
        new_str.append(n)

print "/".join(new_str)
```